# Как извлечь строку из textarea, обработать ее как jquery объект и вставить обратно

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

textarea содержит строку, хочу обработать ее средствами jquery, найти html объекты и выполнить с ними некоторые действия. 
Добавить стили классы, обертки, а затем результат вставить обратно.

Делаю это следующим образом:

```js
$html = $($('textarea').val());
$html.find('h2').css('font-size', 36);
$html.wrap('<div class="main>"');
$('textarea').val($html.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
<h1 class="rtecenter" style="font-size: 18px;  font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
  Заголовок моего текста</h1>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 55%;">
        &nbsp;</td>
      <td>Это справочный текст справа бла бла бла</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Базовый пакет "большой большой пакет" - стоимость</h2>

<p>
  довольно простой и потыняй текст ставленный в абзац</p>

<p>
  <span style="font-size:10px">А вот еще небольшой текст</span></p>

<p>
  Так же рекомендуется посмотреть эту таблицу:</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:70%">
        Кнопка «НАВЕРХ»</td>
      <td>
        500 руб</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Форма</td>
      <td>
        700 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Поиск</td>
      <td>
        700 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Коробка</td>
      <td>
        1800 руб.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
  <strong>А это последняя строка которая выводится после таблицы</strong></p>

<p>
  От всех модулей из дополнительного функционала можно отказаться.</p>
</textarea>
```

но результат совсем не тот, что я ожидал получить. 
В textarea после выполнения преобразования должен содержаться html:

```
<div class="main">
<h1 class="rtecenter" style="font-size: 18px;  font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
      Заголовок моего текста</h1>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 55%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td>Это справочный текст справа бла бла бла</strong></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <h2 style="font-size: 36px">Базовый пакет "большой большой пакет" - стоимость</h2>

    <p>
      довольно простой и потыняй текст ставленный в абзац</p>

    <p>
      <span style="font-size:10px">А вот еще небольшой текст</span></p>

    <p>
      Так же рекомендуется посмотреть эту таблицу:</p>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:70%">
            Кнопка «НАВЕРХ»</td>
          <td>
            500 руб</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Форма</td>
          <td>
            700 руб.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Поиск</td>
          <td>
            700 руб.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Коробка</td>
          <td>
            1800 руб.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p>
      <strong>А это последняя строка которая выводится после таблицы</strong></p>

    <p>
      От всех модулей из дополнительного функционала можно отказаться.</p>
</div>
```

Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko дополнил вопрос

Comment: jquery объект грубо говоря есть 1 dom элемент. У вас в textarea несколько лежащих рядом (h1, table, p и тд). Попробуйте сначала значение textarea оберунуть в div, к примеру. А затем уже сделать из этого jquery объект и присвоить $html

Comment: Также неплохо было бы вставить валдиный HTML в textarea, а потом уже пытаться его парсить.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в примере вполне валидный html в textarea

Comment: @InDevX правда? А вы его проверяли? http://prntscr.com/nscqws Открывающие теги (strong) уже не обязательны?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Представьте себе, [правда](http://prntscr.com/nsct2z)... Да, проверял, и получается что не обязательны.

Comment: @InDevX смешно, конечно) Вы проверяете тег textarea, в котором находится текст, который конечно может быть любым :-) А вы проверьте содержимое textarea. Надеюсь, вы понимаете, о чем я. http://prntscr.com/nsddjg

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, понимаю. Ещё удивлялся чего проходит. Не знал что содержимое не учитывается при проверке (да и пользуюсь ей крайне редко)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обоих случаях заранее создан невидимый `<div style="display: none;">`, куда сперва помещается код из textarea, чтобы можно было использовать все фишки, как с обычным кодом, а не работать только с текстом.

jQuery:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/vfg1cuL9/)

```js
(function(){

$('#hide').html( $('#bubu').val() );
/* Всем h2 внутри #hide задаем 36px размер */
$('#hide h2').css('fontSize', '36px');

/* Когда уже больше нечего делать с реальным HTML, получаем его в виде строки и извращаемся дальше */
var html = $('#hide').html();

html = html.replace(/\n/g,'\n' + '  ').replace(/^/g,'  ');
html = '<div class="main">\n' + html + '\n</div>';

$('#bubu').val( html );

})();
```

```css
textarea {width: 700px; height: 250px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hide" style="display: none;"></div>

<textarea id="bubu">
<h1 class="rtecenter" style="font-size: 18px;  font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
  Заголовок моего текста</h1>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 55%;">
        &nbsp;</td>
      <td>Это справочный текст справа бла бла бла</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Базовый пакет "большой большой пакет" - стоимость</h2>

<p>
  довольно простой и потыняй текст ставленный в абзац</p>

<p>
  <span style="font-size:10px">А вот еще небольшой текст</span></p>

<p>
  Так же рекомендуется посмотреть эту таблицу:</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:70%">
        Кнопка «НАВЕРХ»</td>
      <td>
        500 руб</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Форма</td>
      <td>
        700 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Поиск</td>
      <td>
        700 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Коробка</td>
      <td>
        1800 руб.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
  <strong>А это последняя строка которая выводится после таблицы</strong></p>

<p>
  От всех модулей из дополнительного функционала можно отказаться.</p>
</textarea>
```

То же самое на JS:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/qvw31abx/)

```js
(function(){

let hide = document.getElementById('hide');
let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');
hide.innerHTML = bubu.value;
/* Теперь внутри hide реальные HTML-элементы, и с ними можно работать как с обычным кодом */

/* Находим все теги h2 ВНУТРИ hide и меняем их размер */
let h2 = hide.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for( let i = 0; i < h2.length; i++ ){
  h2[i].style.fontSize = '36px';
}/* jQuery за кулисами выполняет тот же цикл */

/*Завершили работу с элементами, получаем html как строку и дальше работаем со строкой*/
let html = hide.innerHTML;
/* \n - перенос строчки. Заменяем его на перенос + 2 пробела  */
/* ^ - начало строчки. Его тоже заменяем на 2 пробела */
html = html.replace(/\n/g,'\n' + '  ').replace(/^/g,'  ');
/* Чтобы далее обернуть его в новый тег и код получился красивше */
html = '<div class="main">\n' + html + '\n</div>';

/* Возвращаем значение textarea на место */
bubu.value = html;

})();
```

```css
textarea {width: 700px; height: 250px;}
```

```html
<div id="hide" style="display: none;"></div>

<textarea id="bubu">
<h1 class="rtecenter" style="font-size: 18px;  font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
  Заголовок моего текста</h1>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 55%;">
        &nbsp;</td>
      <td>Это справочный текст справа бла бла бла</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Базовый пакет "большой большой пакет" - стоимость</h2>

<p>
  довольно простой и потыняй текст ставленный в абзац</p>

<p>
  <span style="font-size:10px">А вот еще небольшой текст</span></p>

<p>
  Так же рекомендуется посмотреть эту таблицу:</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:70%">
        Кнопка «НАВЕРХ»</td>
      <td>
        500 руб</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Форма</td>
      <td>
        700 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Поиск</td>
      <td>
        700 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Коробка</td>
      <td>
        1800 руб.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
  <strong>А это последняя строка которая выводится после таблицы</strong></p>

<p>
  От всех модулей из дополнительного функционала можно отказаться.</p>
</textarea>
```

Если с регулярными выражениями не бубу, [regex101 (помогает легче их писать)](https://regex101.com/)

[Шпаргалка по регулярным выражениям](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)